# Im getting a TypeError: 'str' object is not callable for the line 179 - python 2.7.11+

Tags: python-2.7

```
Created on Apr 19, 2016
@author: harshitha
import re
import urllib
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import csv
import sys
print(sys.version_info)
print(sys.version)
f = open('/home/harshitha/Documents/house_database.csv', 'w')

zz=0

f.write('Zipcode')
f.write(',')
f.write('Bedrooms')        
f.write(',')
f.write('Bathrooms')
f.write(',')
f.write('Square_Footage')
f.write(',')
f.write('Price_Per_SqFt')
f.write(',')
f.write('Lot_Size')
f.write(',')
f.write('Stories')
f.write(',')
f.write('Property_Type')
f.write(',')
f.write('Year_Built')
f.write(',')
f.write('MLS')
f.write(',')
f.write('Neighborhood')
f.write(',')
f.write('County')
f.write(',')
f.write('Monthly_Est_Motgage ')
f.write(',')
f.write('Monthly_Est_Insurance')
f.write(',')
f.write('Last_Updated')
f.write(',')
f.write('Last_Sold_Date')
f.write(',')
f.write('Last_Sold_Price')
f.write(',')
f.write('\n')

 # Get all the zipcodes
 with open('/home/harshitha/Documents/zip.csv','rU') as csvfile:
 reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
 for row in reader:
    zipcode = row['ZipCode']
    zz = zz + 1

    if zz <3789:
        continue

#from the link
    link = 'http://www.homes.com/property/1416-church-st-san-francisco-      ca-94131/id-100013343668/'
    html = urlopen(link).read()
    parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(html)
    #print parsed_html

Bedrooms = '--'
Bathrooms = '--'
Square_Footage = '--'
Price_Per_SqFt = '--'
Lot_Size = '--'
Stories = '--'
Property_Type = '--'
Year_Built = '--'
MLS = '--'
Neighborhood = '--'
County = '--'
Monthly_Est_Motgage = '--'
Monthly_Est_Insurance = '--'
Last_Updated = '--'
Last_Sold_Date = '--'
Last_Sold_price = '--'

try:
    data = parsed_html.find("dt", text=re.compile("Bedroom(s)"))
    if data is not None:
            Bedrooms = data.parent.findNextSibling("dd").text


    data = parsed_html.find("dt", text=re.compile("Bathroom(s)"))
    if data is not None:
            Bathrooms = data.parent.findNextSibling("dd").text

    data = parsed_html.find("dt", text=re.compile("Square Footage"))
    if data is not None:
            Square_Footage = data.parent.findNextSibling("dd").text

    data = parsed_html.find("dt", text=re.compile("Price Per SqFt "))
    if data is not None:
            Price_Per_SqFt = data.parent.findNextSibling("dd").text

    data = parsed_html.find("dt", text=re.compile("Lot Size"))
    if data is not None:
            Lot_Size = data.parent.findNextSibling("dd").text

    data = parsed_html.find("dt", text=re.compile("Stories"))
    if data is not None:
            data_field = data.parent.findNextSibling("dd")
            if data_field is not None:
                Stories = BeautifulSoup(''.join(data_field[0])).text

    data = parsed_html.find("dt", text=re.compile("Property Type"))
    if data is not None:
            data_field = data.parent.findNext("dt")
            data_field = data.parent.findNextSibling("dd")
            if data_field is not None:
                Apt = BeautifulSoup(''.join(data_field[0])).text
                condo = BeautifulSoup(''.join(data_field[0])).text

    data = parsed_html.find("dt", text=re.compile("YearBuilt"))
    if data is not None:
            Year_Built = data.parent.findNextSibling("dd").text

    data = parsed_html.find("dt", text=re.compile("MLS"))
    if data is not None:
            data_field = data.parent.findNextSibling("dd")
            if data_field is not None:
                MLS = BeautifulSoup(''.join(data_field[0])).text

    data = parsed_html.find("dt", text=re.compile("Neighborhood"))
    if data is not None:
            data_field = data.parent.findNextSibling("dd")
            if data_field is not None:
                Neighborhood  = BeautifulSoup(''.join(data_field[0])).text

    data = parsed_html.find("dt", text=re.compile("County"))
    if data is not None:
            data_field = data.parent.findNextSibling("dd")
            if data_field is not None:
                county  = BeautifulSoup(''.join(data_field[0])).text

    data = parsed_html.find("dt", text=re.compile("Monthly Est Mortgage"))
    if data is not None:
            data_field = data.parent.findNextSibling("dd")
            if data_field is not None:
                Monthly_Est_Mortgage =        BeautifulSoup(''.join(data_field[0])).text

    data = parsed_html.find("dt", text=re.compile("Monthly Est Insurance"))
    if data is not None:
            data_field = data.parent.findNextSibling("dd")
            if data_field is not None:
                Monthly_Est_Insurance = BeautifulSoup(''.join(data_field[0])).text

    data = parsed_html.find("dt", text=re.compile("Last Updated"))
    if data is not None:
            data_field= data.parent.findNextSibling("dd")
            if data_field is not None:
                Last_Updated  = BeautifulSoup(''.join(data_field[0])).text

    data = parsed_html.find("dt", text=re.compile("Last Sold Date"))
    if data is not None:
            data_field= data.parent.findNextSibling("dd")
            if data_field is not None:
                Last_Sold_Date = BeautifulSoup(''.join(data_field[0])).text

    data = parsed_html.find("dt", text=re.compile("Last Sold Price"))
    if data is not None:
            data_field1 = data.parent.findNextSibling("dd")
            if data_field1 is not None:
                Last_Sold_Price = BeautifulSoup(''.join(data_field1[0])).text

except:
print ('')
f.write(zipcode + ',' + Bedrooms.replace(',','')+ ',' +     Bathrooms.replace(',','') + ',' + Square_Footage.replace(',','')+ ',' + Price_Per_SqFt.replace(',','')+ ',' + Lot_Size(',','') + ',' + Stories.replace(',','') )

'''f.write(zipcode + ',' + Bedrooms.replace(',','')+ ',' + Bathrooms.replace(',','') + ',' + Square_Footage.replace(',','') \
            + ',' + Price_Per_SqFt.replace(',','')+ ',' + Lot_Size(',','') + ',' + Stories.replace(',','') \
            + ',' + Property_Type.replace(',','') + ',' +
```

Comment: could any one help me

Comment: In a last line is that a commented out part of a code or some errand bit?

Comment: First, I think the identation is not correctly arranged. You should fix it by hand or using a editor like Sublim.


Second, I think you are trying to find all the data for **each** zipcode in the `zip.csv` file. Am I right? If it is the case, you are not doing the right thing. The for loop in the with statement keep updating the  `zipcode` variable. That is to say, once the for loop ends, the `zipcode` variable will hold only the **last** zipcode in the `zip.csv`.

Comment: actually i have commented to check whether the rest of the code is working or not

Comment: im writing the related scrape data into a csv file. so this is giving me an error ... Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/harshitha/workspace/Application/src/data.py", line 186, in <module>
    + ',' + Last_Sold_Price(',',''))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"""
Created on Apr 19, 2016

@author: harshitha
"""

import re
import urllib
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import csv
import sys
print(sys.version_info)
print(sys.version)
f = open('/home/harshitha/Documents/house_database.csv', 'w')

zz=0
header = ",".join([
'Zipcode', 'Bedrooms', 'Bathrooms', 
'Square_Footage','Price_Per_SqFt', 'Lot_Size', 
'Stories', 'Property_Type', 'Year_Built', 
'MLS', 'Neighborhood', 'County',
'Monthly_Est_Motgage','Monthly_Est_Insurance', 'Last_Updated',
'Last_Sold_Date', 'Last_Sold_Price'
])
f.write(header + "\n")

# Get all the zipcodes
with open('/home/harshitha/Documents/zip.csv','rU') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        zipcode = row['ZipCode']
        zz = zz + 1

        if zz < 3789:
            continue

        #from the link
        link = 'http://www.homes.com/property/1416-church-st-san-francisco-ca-94131/id-100013343668/'
        html = urlopen(link).read()
        parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(html)
        #print parsed_html

        Bedrooms = '--'
        Bathrooms = '--'
        Square_Footage = '--'
        Price_Per_SqFt = '--'
        Lot_Size = '--'
        Stories = '--'
        Property_Type = '--'
        Year_Built = '--'
        MLS = '--'
        Neighborhood = '--'
        County = '--'
        Monthly_Est_Motgage = '--'
        Monthly_Est_Insurance = '--'
        Last_Updated = '--'
        Last_Sold_Date = '--'
        Last_Sold_price = '--'

        try:
            data = parsed_html.find("dt", text=re.compile("Bedroom(s)"))
            if data is not None:
                Bedrooms = data.parent.findNextSibling("dd").text


            data = parsed_html.find("dt", text=re.compile("Bathroom(s)"))
            if data is not None:
                Bathrooms = data.parent.findNextSibling("dd").text

            data = parsed_html.find("dt", text=re.compile("Square Footage"))
            if data is not None:
                Square_Footage = data.parent.findNextSibling("dd").text

            data = parsed_html.find("dt", text=re.compile("Price Per SqFt "))
            if data is not None:
                Price_Per_SqFt = data.parent.findNextSibling("dd").text

            data = parsed_html.find("dt", text=re.compile("Lot Size"))
            if data is not None:
                Lot_Size = data.parent.findNextSibling("dd").text

            data = parsed_html.find("dt", text=re.compile("Stories"))
            if data is not None:
                data_field = data.parent.findNextSibling("dd")
                if data_field is not None:
                        Stories = BeautifulSoup(''.join(data_field[0])).text

            data = parsed_html.find("dt", text=re.compile("Property Type"))
            if data is not None:
                data_field = data.parent.findNext("dt")
                data_field = data.parent.findNextSibling("dd")
                if data_field is not None:
                    Apt = BeautifulSoup(''.join(data_field[0])).text
                    condo = BeautifulSoup(''.join(data_field[0])).text

            data = parsed_html.find("dt", text=re.compile("YearBuilt"))
            if data is not None:
                Year_Built = data.parent.findNextSibling("dd").text

            data = parsed_html.find("dt", text=re.compile("MLS"))
            if data is not None:
                data_field = data.parent.findNextSibling("dd")
                if data_field is not None:
                    MLS = BeautifulSoup(''.join(data_field[0])).text

            data = parsed_html.find("dt", text=re.compile("Neighborhood"))
            if data is not None:
                data_field = data.parent.findNextSibling("dd")
                if data_field is not None:
                    Neighborhood  = BeautifulSoup(''.join(data_field[0])).text

            data = parsed_html.find("dt", text=re.compile("County"))
            if data is not None:
                data_field = data.parent.findNextSibling("dd")
                if data_field is not None:
                    county  = BeautifulSoup(''.join(data_field[0])).text

            data = parsed_html.find("dt", text=re.compile("Monthly Est Mortgage"))
            if data is not None:
                data_field = data.parent.findNextSibling("dd")
                if data_field is not None:
                    Monthly_Est_Mortgage =        BeautifulSoup(''.join(data_field[0])).text

            data = parsed_html.find("dt", text=re.compile("Monthly Est Insurance"))
            if data is not None:
                data_field = data.parent.findNextSibling("dd")
                if data_field is not None:
                    Monthly_Est_Insurance = BeautifulSoup(''.join(data_field[0])).text

            data = parsed_html.find("dt", text=re.compile("Last Updated"))
            if data is not None:
                data_field= data.parent.findNextSibling("dd")
                if data_field is not None:
                    Last_Updated  = BeautifulSoup(''.join(data_field[0])).text

            data = parsed_html.find("dt", text=re.compile("Last Sold Date"))
            if data is not None:
                data_field= data.parent.findNextSibling("dd")
                if data_field is not None:
                    Last_Sold_Date = BeautifulSoup(''.join(data_field[0])).text

            data = parsed_html.find("dt", text=re.compile("Last Sold Price"))
            if data is not None:
                data_field1 = data.parent.findNextSibling("dd")
                if data_field1 is not None:
                    Last_Sold_Price = BeautifulSoup(''.join(data_field1[0])).text

        except:
            print ('')

        f.write(zipcode + ',' + Bedrooms.replace(',','')+ ',' +  Bathrooms.replace(',','') + ',' + Square_Footage.replace(',','')+ ',' + Price_Per_SqFt.replace(',','')+ ',' + Lot_Size(',','') + ',' + Stories.replace(',',''))
f.close()
```